# Large gap between <li> and page margin on blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

So I have been drafting my blog post for a while and I decided it was time to preview it and...

[image: I tell you, a double decker bus could fit through there!]

I found that `<li>` tags are indented quite a way. Is this by design? Or can it be fixed to be slightly less extreme? Is it just me? (FF5, Fedora 15, also the latest stable Google Chrome).

Comment: I think it is by design - on my machine (FF5) it is indented the same amount, but it looks fine on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't totally get rid of it, but I did lessen the indentation on lists.

Comment: Cool, I think that works nicely. I just felt the indentation was a bit extreme as-is. Maybe I should've used paragraph headings instead... but I like my bullet points! Thanks.